# How can I stop my Instagram Feed from being indexed?

Tags: wordpress, instagram, instagram-api, google-search-console

I am using a Instagram Feed on my wordpress website.. However my Images are being indexed by google when I wish them not to be.

Is there anyway to stop these images from being indexed or a alternative plugin I could use?

Thanks in advance for all your help!

EDIT:
This question has now been moved to Wordpress STack Exchange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this snippet,

```
<!--googleoff: index-->
//your instagram feed div
<!--googleon: index>
```

For more information,

- [Preventing Google from indexing the contents of a div by reversing the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11320407/preventing-google-from-indexing-the-contents-of-a-div-by-reversing-the-string)
- [Tell Google to Not Index Certain Parts of Your Page](https://perishablepress.com/tell-google-to-not-index-certain-parts-of-your-page/)
- [Excluding Unwanted Text from the Index](https://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/70/gsa_doc_set/admin_crawl/preparing.html#1076243)

Hope this will helps you.